# Is my method for proving this implication correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My professor put up the lecture slides from today's lecture and I decided to go over the proof again since I didn't quite catch it in class. I think I found something wrong with her proof. Please let me know if mine is correct or if I am wrong:

Proving an Implication:

Theorem: If $0\le x\le 2$ then $-x^3+4x+1>0$

Proof:

1. Assume $0\le x\le 2$
2. Then $0\le x^2\le 4$ (since $0\le a,b\quad \& \quad a\le b\Rightarrow a^2\le b^2$)
3. $-4\le -x^2\le 0$
4. $0\le -x^2+4\le 4$
5. $0\le x(-x^2+4)\le 4x$
6. $0\le -x^3+4x\le 4x$
7. $1\le -x^3+4x+1\le 4x+1$
8. More specifically, $-x^3+4x+1>0$

The proof from the lecture slides:

[image]

Comment: Your proof is fine - which does not imply her proof is wrong, though

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please look over the proof from the lecture. I added it.

Comment: Looks good.  But that doesn't mean there's anything wrong with hers.  Mine would be far shoter.  (O<x < 2 so x^2 < 4x so x^3 < 4x so -x^3 - 4x + 1 > 1 >0)

Comment: The minus in front of $4x$ in the slides has to be a typo. Just as in @fleablood's version.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with hers.  Hers is fine too.

Comment: @fleablood As string said, the minus signs are slightly off.

Comment: In her proof lines 4-8 have a typo $-4$ must be $+4$. In the theorem statement it is correct sign.

Comment: In fact what the heck is different between yours and hers.  They're same so far as I can tell (except you stated but never used <= 4x+1)

Comment: Oh, it's a typo.

Comment: BTW, I would not hesitate to jump directly to $$-x^3+4x=x(4-x^2)\geq 0$$ from which the result should immediately be clear, but that is just a matter of taste.

Comment: @String Would you be able to state your first answer in the comments and the reason why you wouldn't immediately jump to that conclusion in an answer below? I will accept it and +1.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: I tried, but you are not obliged to accept or upvote my answer. But feel free to comment, suggest improvements, ask for clarifications etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a matter of taste, but I would not hesitate to jump directly to
$$
-x^3+4x=x(4-x^2)
$$
which must be greater than or equal to zero since both factors, $x$ and $4-x^2$, are evidently non-negative for $0\leq x\leq 2$. This is merely summarizing what you already stated yourself. So $-x^3+4x\geq 0$ and thus
$$
-x^3+4x+1\geq 1>0
$$

---

Regarding the slides, it does NOT make sense to state that
$$
0\leq -x^3-4x=-(x^3+4x)
$$
which is clearly false for any positive value of $x$. Thus the minus sign in $-4x$ must be a typo in the slides.